# Regular Expression of Negative Lookbehind in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I am using R to extract string of "***** END OF REPORT *****", there are plenty of it in the middle of the report and I only want to extract the last "***** END OF REPORT *****" in the end of report.

A is not what I want to extract, cause it is not the real end of the report, it is followed by the next part of report; B is the one I want, cause it is the end of the report followed by some symbols, no other information after that.

A:

```
"    ***** END OF REPORT *****

¿     ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------------------------------------------------------------
AABBCC00/A1                                    G E N E R A L  L E D G E R                    
EFF DATE : 01/02/2019 PAGE :    1
AA111                                  GL TRANSACTION LISTING FROM 01/01/2019 
TO 31/01/2019       RUN DATE : 02/02/2019 AT 01:09:15

----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------------------------------------------------------"
```

B:

```
"     ***** END OF REPORT *****

·         +      ~      ,      o;      J      óX      cg      v      
Ô”     ¡¢     Å°     ô¾     Í     ‘Û"
```

Below is the regex I have written so far, but it doesn't work properly.

```
str_detect(A,"(\\Q*****\\E END OF REPORT \\Q*****\\E\n.+)(?!--------------------$)" )
```

A should return FALSE; B should return TRUE (real end).

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract from the report? (I guess it is not just the line with "end of report". For instance, do you need 3 lines after that? or?)

Comment: I posted an answer which allows to find the line of the last occurrence of "end of report". But I can modify it to extract a number of lines after it if this is what you ultimately want to do

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to the problem which returns the line number of the last occurrence of the string "END OF REPORT":

```
library(stringr)

report <- readLines("/path/of/your/report")

tail(str_which(report, ".*END OF REPORT.*"), n = 1L)
```

This code reads in your report and turns it into a character vector in which each line is one element. `str_which()` returns the line numbers (in fact, the indexes) in which the string "END OF REPORT" appears, and `tail()` gives you the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
report[which.max(grepl("END OF REPORT", report[c(1)]))]
```